# How to pass array of structs that is within one function to another function through main

Tags: c

Hey so I have this function called setup and in this function, an array of structs is declared and filled.

```
void setup (void){

        struct wall walls[COUNT]
        // It is then filled using a loop
}
```

However, within the `main()` function I have another function setup like this:

```
int main(){
    setup_bar(walls, COUNT_LINES);
    return 0;
}
```

But it is saying it cant access walls within `setup_bar()`. I'm trying to pass the walls array from one function to another that is in main. The struct array isn't declared globally because its size is not known until the `setup()` function runs. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to do, `struct wall walls` is a local variable which doesn't exist after `setup` function returns to main. You might want to look at [dynamic memory allocation in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Comment: You would have the same problem if the variable were of any other type. I think you need to study some more about variable scope and how to write, and use, functions before adding the complications of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following:

> The struct array isn't declared globally because its size is not known until the `setup()` function runs.

Then your only option seems to be dynamically allocating such array using `malloc()` and returning it to the caller, like this:

```
struct wall *setup (void) {
    struct wall *walls;

    size_t needed;

    /* Calculate the needed size... */

    // Allocate the array:
    walls = malloc(needed * sizeof(struct wall));

    /* Fill the array with a loop... */

    // Return it:
    return walls;
}

int main() {
    struct wall *x;

    x = setup();
    setup_bar(x, COUNT_LINES);

    /* whatever else... */

    // Remember to free the allocated array once you're done using it:
    free(x);

    return 0;
}
```

---

By the way, the fact that you say that the size is not known until `setup()` is run, together with this declaration:

```
struct wall walls[COUNT];
```

really makes me wonder which one of the two statements is wrong... did you use `COUNT` here just as an example or what? If you use a `#define` or other global variable then the size **is** known before `setup()` is run.

Comment: Probably `COUNT` was just an example.

Comment: How likely is it that the OP will just copy your code and leave (i.e. not look at it at all)?

Comment: @JL2210 that's a really good question. I ask that to myself in my sleep every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This is a limitation of a thing called *storage duration*.

Basically, once `setup` exits, `wall` is destroyed. You cannot access it again.

To get around this, create two static global variables, `wall` and `wall_size`:

```
static struct wall *walls;
static size_t wall_size;
```

and then allocate them in `setup`:

```
walls = malloc(COUNT*sizeof(*walls));
wall_size = COUNT;
```

That way, `walls` will be available to all functions in the translation unit (basically the `.c` file you're using). You can then traverse `walls` using `wall_size`.

Comment: sizeof pointer? probably meant `struct wall`

Comment: @Tony Nope, I meant what I wrote. This dereferences `walls` and then takes the size of `struct wall` (indirectly). Never use a type name for `sizeof` in `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with the code is that you are using a wrong pattern.

Define the function `setup` the following way

```
void setup( struct wall * walls, size_t n)
{
        // It is then filled using a loop
}
```

and in main write

```
int main( void )
{
    struct wall walls[COUNT_LINES];

    setup( walls, COUNT_LINES );
    setup_bar( walls, COUNT_LINES );
    //...

    return 0;
}
```

Another approach is the following that is to allocate dynamically an array of structures in the function setup. In this case the functions can look like

```
size_t setup_bar( struct wall **walls )
{
    *walls = malloc( COUNT, sizeof( struct wall ) );

    size_t n = *walls == NULL ? 0 : COUNT;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        // It is then filled using a loop
    }

    return n;
}

int main( void )
{
    struct wall *walls = NULL;

    size_t n = setup( &walls );

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        setup_bar( walls, n );
    }
    //...
    free( walls );

    return 0;
}
```